# Windows Installer custom action should impersonate the user to connect to the database but instead attempts to connect as the local machine

Tags: windows-installer, impersonation, failed-installation

The user is running a Windows Installer .msi file (it is started by double-clicking Setup.exe). The installer uses a custom action to connect to an SQL Server database, therefore it should use impersonation.

The logged-on user is a domain user account which is a local administrator on the machine and has permissions in SQL Server to connect.

The SQL Server log shows that the connection to the database was attempted as the local system user on the machine, not the logged-in user, which means the impersonation did not work in the custom action.

The custom action is defined as,

```
<CustomAction Id="ConnectSql" DllEntry="ConnectSql" BinaryKey="ConnectToSql" Execute="immediate"/>
```

I have checked the type of the custom action in the .msi file (with Orca) and it is 1, as I would expect; this means the custom action will be executed immediately and with impersonation. The connection to the database uses integrated login security (Windows Authentication) therefore the custom action should impersonate the user in order to be able to connect to the database.

In my tests, the impersonation causes the custom action to connect to the database as the logged-in user and everything works correctly. My tests include a simulation of the customer's environment with the installer running on the client and the database on a separate server, with both machines members of the domain and the user logged on to the client as a domain user who is a local administrator.

I'm not able to reproduce a situation in which the connection to the database fails. I have run out of ideas about what could be causing it not to work, except that perhaps it has something to do with the domain profile. Is that a possibility? What do I need to check next to resolve this failure?

Some relevant lines from the log file:

```
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:241]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:241]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:241]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:241]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:241]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:241]: Running product '{4E1537C7-A4CE-4312-AFEC-13921676A2CA}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:241]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MSIFASTINSTALL property. Its value is '1'.
[...]
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:257]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:266]: MSI_LUA: Setting AdminUser property to 1 because this is the client or the user has already permitted elevation
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:266]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:266]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:266]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:266]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (E8:98) [09:37:44:266]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'Windows User'.
```

Comment: Try to generate verbose logging /l*vx filename.log and share the relevant lines where custom action is failing.

Comment: @VivekJaiswal Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, that might help but I don't have access directly and am trying to solve this with the limited information I have.

Comment: This was solved in the end but I don't know why; it just started working. I think it is something to do with the Windows domain configuration or the domain users. Something was changed by IT support but no-one knows what.